# Migrating oracle 11g to 19c using Jooq 3.7.1 version degrades performance(insertion) on database significantly

Tags: oracle11g, jooq, oracle19c, jooq-codegen-maven

Currently we are using jooq 3.7.1 pro version and oracle 11g database in our application. Now we need to upgrade database from 11g to 19c, So we used ojdbc8.jar to connect to oracle 19c and passing ORACLE12C dialect as Jooq 3.7.1 provides dialect until 12C only.

After upgrading to 19C, While running the performance test, Insertion in database is very slow.

My question is, is it because of ORACLE12C dialect in jooq 3.7.1?

Do we really need to upgrade the jooq version as well to overcome this performance degradation?

Comment: Why do you use this very old jOOQ version but a new Oracle version? You should update the jOOQ version as well

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what is slow, specifically?

Comment: @LukasEder, Actually while doing the performance test, data insertion from cache to oracle 19c is very slow with jOOQ 3.7.1(using dialect 12c). But if we point to oracle 11g, it's pretty fast.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. But how can we help you? There could be hundreds of reasons why it's slow/fast. Have you checked execution plans? Have you checked your server configurations? Have you checked performance using JDBC directly? Have you run benchmarks, comparing performance using a PL/SQL block, for example (ideas here: https://www.jooq.org/benchmark). The way you asked your question so far, there's no way anyone could help you. Please show what you already know, what you've already checked, etc. Some ideas can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example